# When the ball moves at a high speed, it is possible for it to penetrate the paddle. This certainly makes the game less realistic

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

When the speed is very high, the ball will penetrate the paddle, to solve this problem I've to try to use 'Intersect' the ball-rectangle and paddles-rectangle, but penetrate still occur. The following is the origin collision method,b is the ball, p is paddle. Moreover, I try to set if the ball didn't hit the top, left, right, bottom, or the paddle2, then it must hit the paddle1. The result is we can't define the state when ball is flying.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks

```
private bool CollisionOccurred()
        {
            // assume no collision
            bool retval = false;

            // heading towards player one
            if (m_ball.DX < 0)
            {
                Rectangle b = m_ball.Rect;
                Rectangle p = m_paddle1.Rect;
                retval =
                    b.Left < p.Right &&
                    b.Right > p.Left &&
                    b.Top < p.Bottom &&
                    b.Bottom > p.Top;
            }
            // heading towards player two
            else // m_ball.DX > 0
            {
                Rectangle b = m_ball.Rect;
                Rectangle p = m_paddle2.Rect;
                retval =
                    b.Left < p.Right &&
                    b.Right > p.Left &&
                    b.Top < p.Bottom &&
                    b.Bottom > p.Top;
            }

            return retval;
```

Comment: Now, I have an idea is change ball.rectangle and paddle.rectangle to a cuboid. Then, I think the ball can't penetrate paddle anymore. Is this workable?

Comment: What you're looking for here is called 'continuous collision detection'. Sorry I don't have time to write a whole answer but I think that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add velocity of the ball (like a margin) for each of your sides of the rectangle.

```
retval = b.Left - b.velocity.X < p.Right &&b.Right+ b.velocity.X > p.Left &&b.Top- b.velocity.Y < p.Bottom &&b.Bottom+ b.velocity.Y > p.Top;
```